# Swift -is it necessary to call continue when leaving a dispatchGroup

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchgroup

I have a group of objects that I have to iterate through using a `for-loop` and `DispatchGroup`. When leaving the group inside the `for-loop`, is calling `continue` necessary?

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

for object in objects {

    group.enter()

    if object.property == nil {
         group.leave()
         continue // does calling this have any effect even though the group is handling it?
    }

    // do something with object and call group.leave() when finished
}
group.notify(...
```

Comment: By the way, you allude to “do something with object” ... Needless to say, if that “something” is not asynchronous, then you shouldn’t be using groups at all.

Comment: @Rob thanks, I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible just to get straight to the point. I wouldn’t use this for a regular loop. I actually use it to pull some data from Firebase where I have to go through multiple ref eg **postsRef > blockedRef > userIdRef > followingRef**

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely necessary to call `continue`, since you want to avoid continuing the execution of the body of your loop.

Calling `DispatchGroup.leave` does not exit the current scope, you need to call `continue` to achieve that. `leave` only affects whatever you are doing with the `DispatchGroup` - so consequent `notify` or `wait` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way this is written, the `continue` is critical, as you want to make sure that the `enter` call has a single `leave` call. Since you're calling `enter` before the `if` test, then you must `leave` and `continue`. If you don’t have the `continue` statement, it will proceed with the subsequent code which is calling `leave` already.

But this `leave`/`continue` pattern is not needed if you just call `enter` *after* the `if` statement:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

for object in objects {    
    if object.property == nil {
         continue
    }

    group.enter()

    // do something with object and call group.leave() when finished
}
group.notify(queue: .main) { ... }
```

I'd then take that a step further and remove that `if` with the `continue` statement. Just add a `where` clause to the `for` loop, eliminating the need for the `continue` at all:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

for object in objects where object.property != nil {
    group.enter()

    // do something with object and call group.leave() when finished
}

group.notify(queue: .main) { ... }
```

This accomplishes what your original code snippet did, but is more concise.

Comment: Hi, quick question. When using the `where` clause in a loop as in `for object in objects where object.postId == postId { }`, is there a need to add a `break` if the loop finds what it is looking for? Without `where` once it finds it, call `break` to exit the loop because there is no need to iterate any further. But I'm not clear if `where` automatically triggers `break`.

Comment: It depends upon your intent. If you really wanted to do it only for the first match, then the whole dispatch group pattern doesn’t make sense. The purpose for dispatch group is to know when all the asynchronous tasks are done. A “group” of one doesn’t make much sense. Lol.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've been more clear, I meant without DispatchGroup, just a regular for-loop. And you're right, one group doesn't make sense, lol

Comment: If you only wanted the first one, you probably wouldn’t use a `for` loop, either, even with `where` clause. Just [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) is probably appropriate if you just want the first entry that matches your `where` clause.

Comment: hmmmm, you're right about that, thanks! I have a bunch of for-loops where I search for one entry and I use break. I never thought about using `first(where)`. Thanks for the advice :)